# Using regex in javascript to cut out substring

Tags: javascript, regex

There are some strings

```
"string numbe1 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value1)"
"string numbe2 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value2)"
"string numbe3 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value3)"
"string numbe5 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value1)"
"string numbe5 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value2)"
```

`(valueN)` can be either `(value1)` or `(value2)` or `(value3)`. I need to cut it from the original string by using javascript regex. So the newString must be kind of `string numbe1 fdsf gfdgfdgf`

Here is what I did (and which is not working as I want)

```
var newString = originalString.replace(/(value1)|(value2)|(value3)/g,"") ;
```

It returns `"1 ()"`.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the parenthesis, and you have an extra `.` right before `replace`

```
"string numbe5 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value2)".replace(/\(value[1-3]\)/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`var newString = originalString.replace(/\(value\d\)/g,"") ;`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
> var s = "string numbe1 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value1)";
> s.replace(/^(.*) \(value[1-3]\)$/, '$1');
"string numbe1 fdsf gfdgfdgf"
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd use this regular expression:

```
"string numbe5 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value2)".replace(/ \(value[123]\)/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly extensible, but if your string formats are *always* the same you could just do this:

```
var str = "string numbe1 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value1)";
str = str.slice(0, str.length-8));​
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the code, Use the code given below

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str="string numbe1 fdsf gfdgfdgf (value2)"; 
var n=str.replace(/(\(value1\)|\(value2\)|\(value3\))/g," ");
alert(n);
}
</script>
```